# Terraform apply command not using its state file from azure blob storage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have terraform state in azure blob storage account and I am referring this terraform state in my jenkins pipeline.

I am using terraform init command which is referring this terraform state in blob storage by using "-backend-config" parameter like below.

```
terraform init -input=false \
                  -backend-config="resource_group_name=RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME" \
                  -backend-config="storage_account_name=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME" \
                  -backend-config="container_name=CONTAINER_NAME" \
                  -backend-config="key=STATE_FILE_NAME"
```

After that I am running terraform plan command which is writing it's data into terraform state which is in azure blob storage and I can see that this file is getting updated in blob storage account.

But, when I am running terraform apply command then it is looking for its terraform state locally and my jenkins pipeline is getting failed.

So, I have tried providing same terraform state file name which is in azure blob storage but still it is getting failed as it is looking for this file locally in jenkins pipeline.
Hence, wanted to check how can I enforce my terraform apply command to get its terraform state file from azure blob storage by default like terraform plan command is automatically referring it's terraform state file from azure blob storage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's better to hardcode those values in the terraform backend provider since you will not change this very often. Changing this configuration will have a massive impact on your infrastructure. These values are not secret, especially if you pass them in a shell that keeps history.

Using `environment` variables for azure credentials is recommended. If you want to specify a backend, please pass a file like this.

azurecreds.conf:

```
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="123"
ARM_CLIENT_ID = "123"
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="123"
ARM_TENANT_ID="123"
```

`terraform init -backend-config=azurecreds.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, yes these values are also provided and that's why my terraform plan command is working and it is updating terraform state file in blob storage. But the issue which I am facing is with terraform apply command as it is not able to pick it's terraform state file from blob storage.

Comment: This is the command which I am providing.
sh "terraform apply -input=false"

Now, like terraform plan how it would recognize that it should refer it's terraform state file from blob storage?

Comment: @svw1105 if your planning stage is correct and reading the state from the blob storage. Please add `-out=plan1` to your planning command. When applying please using `terraform apply --auto-approve -input=false plan1 `. 

Please try this and let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it is working. But this command will create a plan1 file locally and terraform apply command will refer it from local disk. Now, how can I verify whether terraform apply command is referring the same state file from blob storage?

Comment: This way it's reading the `plan` from localdisk. This does not mean your `state` is local. Make a change in your Terraform by adding a resource (e.g. small VM). After applying this change, go in your blob storage and check `last updated time` of your state file. You can also download it and check if the VM is added in the remote state.

Comment: yes you are right and it has solved my issue. Thanks!!